# Is it legal for a standard library implementation to specialize a function templated on a concept with a child concept?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

With the c++11 and c++14 library concepts, may a valid implementation of the c++ standard library create a specialized version of a function templated on a concept to take advantage of the additional functionality of child concept for optimizations that would not be possible with the base concept alone, such as with the `InputIterator` constructor of `std::vector`, and iterators which fulfill the requirements of `RandomAccessIterator`?

```
// specified by standard
vector(InputIt begin, InputIt end, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
// is this specialization allowed in an implementation if it provides the same functionality?
vector(RandomAccessIt begin, RandomAccessIt end, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Here, `InputIt` is a type fulfilling the requirements of the [`InputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) concept, and `RandomAccessIt` fulfills the requirements of [`RandomAccessIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). Notably, this concept lacks a requirement for finding the difference between two iterators, while its great-grandchild concept `RandomAccessIterator` *does* require

```
It a,b;
It::difference_type c = a - b;
```

to be valid. Finding the difference between two iterators would be a help to the `InputIterator` constructor for `std::vector` in the cases where `RandomAccessIterator` is also a concept fulfilled by the supplied iterators, since it would allow an implementation to pre-allocate the space required by the final vector, rather than resizing it multiple times during construction.

I can see it being valid, because of the Standard's occasional use of as-if rules, such as with covariant return types for virtual functions in inheritance hierarchies. However, there are rather *distinct* differences between the situations, so I can also see that the logic behind covariant return types may not necessarily have transferred to this situation.

---

To reiterate: may a valid implementation of the c++ standard library create a specialized version of a function templated on a concept to take advantage of the additional functionality of child concept for optimizations that would not be possible with the base concept alone?

---

*Note: I've not tagged this question with [c++-concepts](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-concepts) because as far as I can tell that tag is for Concepts-Lite and the Concepts TS, and this question is about the library concepts in c++11 and c++14*

Comment: Suppose you had some RandomAccessIterators `a` and `b`; wouldn't `vector(a, b)` be ambiguous?

Comment: @immibis I was assuming the rules would be the same as for partial specialization of templates, where the more specific version of the function would win.

Comment: Member functions are a bad example, the standard already allows implementations to alter their signatures to their hearts' content as long as a plain call to a signature in the standard works as specified. It's more interesting with non-members, but implementations can always call overloaded `__helpers` instead of adding overloads directly, and without the concepts TS's overload resolution support they have to do it anyway.

Comment: @T.C. But you can't actually declare the constructor as `vector(RandomAccessIterator a, RandomAccessIterator b, ...)`, because concepts aren't actually a language feature, right? You have to do `template<class T> vector(T a, T b, ...)` and rely on SFINAE.

Comment: @immibis Correct. Or tag dispatch to an internal helper, which is more likely to happen. "Specializing" that constructor for forward-or-better iterators is required by the standard, in any event.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you. Are there any handy quotes from the standard, or is this more of a distributed affair? I tried looking in n4140, but I'm not familiar enough with it to find any clause dealing with library concepts in general, which is where I'm *assuming* such a quote would be. :\

Comment: libstdc++ takes advantage of random access iterators; have a look at their implementation. In standard C++ that's definitely allowed, and I haven't seen a new "standard library" yet that uses the Concepts TS.

Comment: So we're saying that the answer to this question is "yes", right?

Comment: @KerrekSB I didn't think to look at an open source library implementation. Something to do with my future questions before posting them, I suppose. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardHodges to me, it looks like "yes" with a side dish of "doesn't need to be allowed because the implementation can specialize the implementation without altering the interface." I'm mostly waiting for someone to post an answer with relevant quotes from the standard now.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `std::distance`? `std::distance` is defined for `InputIt`, but has special semantics for `RandomIt` (e.g. it's `last - first` and not the number of `first++` till `first == last`). Implementation is done via `iterator_tag` dispatch, as far as I know, so no fancy concept overloading there (at least for now). See `[iterator.operatons]` (N3337).

Comment: @Zeta sort of--I'm more looking for language in the standard for the general case of validity of specialization for more detailed concepts, rather than any specific instance, though as mentioned above the point is somewhat moot since an implementation can just do something like tag dispatch to a set of helpers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to determine externally which constructor you have invoked with a given signature in C++.

So the exact details of the `vector` signature can be varied under the as-if rule so long as all constructors that are specified can be invoked, the behavior you get at satisfies the documented features, and any constructor arguments that would not have been valid remain invalid (as external code can do SFINAE testing to determine if a given set of arguments would construct a `std::vector`).

As noted by the OP and comments, many standard library implementations just use tag dispatching to forward to more-efficient more-specialized versions.

Of interest would be the answer *outside* of the context of a constructor, where you can detect functions having specific signatures (and not just compatibility), and you can distinguish between distinct functions.  I do not know the answer here, but I am under the (unvalidated) impression that functions that do not match the exact signatures described in the standard actually occur in `std` libraries sometimes.